# Yet another "could not load file or assembly ... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: .net, sqlite, nunit, 32bit-64bit

I have a dll with NUnit tests that had been working fine. I converted it from an Any CPU to an x86 project because I need to use SQLite reliably across different platforms, so I need to include the 32-bit System.Data.SQLite.dll and let everything reference that.

Anyway, after conversion, NUnit gives that error when trying to load the dll.

I don't think this will be enlightening at all, but here is the stack trace:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly ... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

The dll I'm trying to test references another one in the same solution. Everything works fine when I run the GUI that this eventually all gets used in, but the tests won't load.

**Update**

The file that can't be loaded is the assembly under test, which is just MyAppName.Test.dll.

Comment: May I know what are the files that cannot be loaded? NUnit.Framework.dll? or something else?

Comment: See update. (Darn, we can't use whitespace to reach the character limit any more.)

Comment: Is the reference to NUnit hitting the GAC or does nunit.framework.dll copy locally?

Comment: Have you tried using the fusion log viewer (fuslogvw.exe) to get more details? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx

Comment: NUnit is copied locally.

Comment: Please post Fusion Log Viewer link as answer so I can mark it. I used it to find the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the fusion log viewer [fuslogvw.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx). It should give you more details about the problem.